# mocha: command not found in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

[image]

[image]

I want to try CI/CD. So I am working on a simple project. I wanted to run the test file. But I get the error "mocha: command not found". There is no problem when I try it in my own terminal. How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"mocha: command not found" means you have to install mocha in your gitlab runner environment.

```
test:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - npm install --global mocha
    - mocha test
```